# Using box shadow on select inputs in Chrome

Tags: css

I am currently working on a small site, and I have used the box-shadow effect on various elements on the site. It seems to work on all the elements where it has been applied, in both Chrome and Firefox, except for `select` and `input`. It will work fine for these input types in Firefox but not in Chrome. Any ideas why?

I have applied this effect using `box-shadow`, `-webkit-box-shadow` and `-moz-box-shadow` for multiple browser support.

Comment: Any chance you can post a link to the page in question (or at least an example)?

Comment: dev.anthonyhindle.co.uk/blog/add The select input is towards the bottom. If you view this in chrome there is no shadow, but there is in firefox.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a workaround:

HTML:

```
<div><input type="text" /></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #666;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/UD2QP/

Comment: I have shadows working fine on text inputs, it is select inputs that don't seem to work.

Comment: Solution still applies, wrap your inconsistently-styleable nodes with consistently-styleable nodes.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - You rock! Your solution is really easy, but it works great! Should have thought about it myself!

Comment: while this works, this is adding unnecessary code bloat for the purpose of presentation. just fyi

Comment: Pick your battles. I think the argument of separating logic from presentation holds true, but that would probably apply more to something like `<i><small><span align="left" width="400" height="400">Foobar</span></small></i>`

Comment: @AlienWebguy This is working fine but that wrapper div has no border radius while the select (on mac at least) has some radius and looks strange, right?

Comment: You could easily remove the border completely from the input and add the radius to the div.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea as it adds code bloat just to fix one  bug in one browser. It also only "fixes" the problem as long as you're doing outset shadows: http://jsfiddle.net/UD2QP/690/

Answer (score 14):

Here's a/the solution:

```
select {-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none; }
```

This allows any shadow CSS to apply to SELECT items in Chrome - but removes any other details such as the drop-down arrow. But simply create a small background img (using screen grab) to reinstate this.

You could wrap this CSS in CSS filters to target only Chrome: E.g.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {/* older safari and older chrome */
  select {-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none; 
}
```

If using SELECTS without a given width, add 'padding-right' CSS to account for the new background icon/img. This has worked perfectly for me.

This also works for HTML5 validation icons, etc, when combining an icon with drop-down arrow in one image).

Answer (score 8):

This is a defect in Chrome, and you should consider avoiding workarounds that add additional code. If you can wait for the fix; wait for it.

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=96192

The defect has been recorded and was "assigned" at the time of this writing.

Comment: The chromium team fixed the defect on April 13, 2013. Hopefully it will find its way into Chrome soon...

Comment: Fixed in Chrome 28 as of now.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I've just done to achieve a thin, faint, outline-like shadow to match my other input controls (which use `box-shadow:0 0 2px #000`) is this:

```
select { border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2); }
```

Resulting in this:

[image: Outlining 'shadow' on HTME select element]

Won't work so comfortably for thicker or offset shadows but neat for this purpose, and doesn't require nesting in other elements or stripping and reinstating all other styles of the element.

Answer (score 1):

use it works 100%

```
-webkit-appearance: none; appearance: none;
```

if there is height problem in safari so add

```
 line-height:18px;
```

Comment: Why `line-height:18px;` how does that help?