# select option text-shadow not rendered

Tags: html, css

I've set the text-shadow css style to the options of a select, but I don't see any browser rendering it.

```
select option {
   text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}
```

If this is not possible, is there any custom browser style to set it without developing my own select box with divs and spans?

Answer (score 2):

the option tag allows very limited styling. for anything fancier then text colour etc you'd need to replace a select/options input with a dom representation (made of divs etc)

there are a few plugins if you don't want to do it from scratch such as [select2](https://select2.github.io/)

here's a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300755/using-box-shadow-on-select-inputs-in-chrome) on a similar topic ( dropshadow on selects) that might also help and here's an article on using [css3 on selects](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit) however its not cross browser compatable so might not be appropriate for your needs. In short, no, I dont think there is a way to add drop shadow on an `option` tag